# Как отправить на email данные, введенные пользователем на сайте?

Tags: php, javascript, html, email

Всем ДД, настоял такой вопрос.

```
  <div id = "form_sample">
<form method= "POST"> 

<p>Имя: </p><p> <input id = "nam" type= "text" name= "name"> </p> 

<p>E-mail: </p><p><input id="ema" type="text" name= "email"></p> 

<p>Комментарий: </p><p><textarea id = "mas" name= "message"></textarea></p> 

<input type= "submit" value= "Отправить" onclick="isEmail()> 
   </form>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе данных в input'ы пользователем, эта информация сразу же отправлялась на email админа. Каким образом такую вещь можно осуществить? (желательно без участия всяких API)

Comment: именно при вводе а не при отправке формы на сервер?)

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция `mail()`

```php
 mail("ваш e-mail", "тема письма", "текст письма");
```

Comment: 1) Скорее всего ТС хочет прямо с фронтенда это делать 2) в подобных ответах крайне рекомендуется давать ссылку на документацию

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать сервис https://formspree.io/
Только html без бекенда.

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://formspree.io/test@mail.com">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```